# File not found exception when running with intellj

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run my application through intellji so I can debug.
When I run this command from the terminal it works:

```
java -cp /Users/craigharley/code/IdeaProjects/decaf-CraigHarley/Skeleton/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar:Compiler.jar decaf.Main -target inter /Users/craigharley/code/IdeaProjects/decaf-CraigHarley/Skeleton/testdata/semantics/illegal-cust.dcf
```

But when I create a build using:

- Edit Build Configs
- New Application
- Select the main class
- Enter `-cp /Users/craigharley/code/IdeaProjects/decaf-CraigHarley/Skeleton/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar:Compiler.jar decaf.Main -target inter /Users/craigharley/code/IdeaProjects/decaf-CraigHarley/Skeleton/testdata/semantics/illegal-cust.dcf` as the program arguments I get a file not found on the `/Users/craigharley/code/IdeaProjects/decaf-CraigHarley/Skeleton/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar:Compiler.jar`, anyone know why this is?

I assume it's because of the `:Compiler.jar`, I don't java much so could somebody explain this to me.

Thanks

Comment: instead of hardwiring the class path into the build config, add the dependencies to the designed build path in IntelliJ - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html for reference

Comment: that worked! thanks